# What does tinfo6 stands for?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack

Working with Haskell and particularly GHC I can see **tinfo6** word quite often. Mostly it appears in arch-vendor-os triple `x86_64-linux-tinfo6` like if it was some sort of OS. But what really does **tinfo6** mean?

Comment: It most likely has something to do with `ncurses` and `libtinfo.so.6`, but why in place of OS in triple for Haskell build?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#ghc-build) are some clues:

> **ghc-build** Specify a specialized architecture bindist to use. Normally this is determined automatically, but you can override the autodetected value here. Possible arguments include `standard`, `gmp4`, `tinfo6`, and `nopie`.

Answer (score 7):

> it appears in arch-vendor-os triple `x86_64-linux-tinfo6`

I think you are confusing GNU target triplets with GHC target triplets. A GHC target triplet is `<architecture>-<operating system>-<ABI>`.

So, `tinfo6` is the ABI. I don't know much about GHC, but I *do* remember that it has a calling convention that is not the C calling convention.

Fun fact: this calling convention can actually not be expressed in C, therefore the C backend of GHC actually calls GCC to generate assembly, then a *Perl*(!!!) script that is part of the GHC compiler searches for calls in the assembly code and re-writes them to the GHC calling convention; after that, the compiler will call GCC (or rather GAS) again, to assemble the object file. (This rather clever but somewhat crazy hack is one of the reasons for the push to native and LLVM backends.)

So, unfortunately, I don't know what `tinfo6` means but I am pretty sure it is the name of the GHC calling convention or ABI.

Comment: Cool fact, I appreciate that. You are correct: it's an ABI, not as OS (shame on me for confusing them).

Comment: Well, in GNU Autoconf triplets, the third element is OS (arch-vendor-os(-kernel)), so it's easy to confuse.

Comment: `tinfo6` has nothing to do with the ABI or calling sequences or anything like that. It is a GHC build variant that links to `libtinfo.so.6` (as opposed to linking to some version of libncurses).